# I want to show data from one column of mysql table in a drop down list,But in drop down it show every entry two times.But i want it only one time

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
|===============================|
| customer_id  | customer_name  |
|===============================|
|  1           |      vick      |
|  2           |      bawa      |
|  3           |      smith     |
|  4           |      goldy     |
|  5           |      jojo      |
=================================
```

There are two columns in table. I have applied the following query.But it shows every name two times but i want every name one time in dropdown.

Please tell me how to show every name only one time in drop down....My second question is that..i want to take the selected value to next page....But first problem is that how to show every name from customer_name single time...But it shows every name two times....Thank you sir

```
<table>
<tr>  
<td>customer name</td>  
<td><select name="customer_name">  
<?php  
$query = 'SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customer_table';  

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
  foreach ($row as $value)  
  {  
    echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_name'] . '</option>';  
  }  
}  
?>  
</select></td>  
</tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: because you have it in a second loop, take the echo out of the foreach.

Comment: remove `foreach` loop

Comment: Consider dropping the old `mysql_*` functions, they are now deprecated. Use PDO or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: Explain the purpose of the `foreach ($row as $value)` loop you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your suolution :
no need of for each...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  

echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_name'] .     '</option>';  

}
```

Comment: @Vick: One question per question, please. This is not a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 loops here which is making it to be repeated.Just remove `foreach($row as $value)`  loop and you will get the result.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    echo '<option value="' . $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_name'] . '</option>'; 
}
```

This would work .